# ‘Submit Review’ button not working, instead add’s product to cart

Tags: php, magento

I have in: `default/style/template/review/form.phtml`

```
<div class="buttons-set"><button type="submit" title="<?php echo $this->__('Submit Review') ?>" class="button"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Submit Review') ?></span></span></button></div>
```

I have in: `app/design/frontend/default/YourTheme/layout/catalog.xml`

```
<block type="review/product_view_list" name="product.info.product_additional_data" as="product_review" template="review/product/view/list.phtml"><block type="review/form" name="product.review.form" as="review_form"/></block>
```

I have in: `app/design/frontend/default/YourTheme/template/catalog/product/view.phtml`

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_review') ?>
```

On the product page have I button Review, if you place a review then don't save the review and the product added to the cart.

Answer (score 2):

Go into your browser and view page source. I'm almost positive you have nested forms. I can't say what the exact structure may be, however, based upon theme edits you could end up with this.

```
<form id="your ID of review>

        <form id="your ID of add to cart>
        </form>
</form>
```

If this happens when you  click submit of the review you could be submitting the add to cart.